# How to Add Color To a Div in XSL when Color is in the XML document

Tags: xslt

I have an XSL 1.0 document with the following:

```
<div class="workgroup_title">
  <xsl:value-of select="./@name"/>
</div>
```

I need to set the color for this element. The color is in the XML file

```
<abc.xyz.color>FF5733</abc.xyz.color>
```

To get it, I use this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="./abc.xyz.color"/>
```

What I would have liked to do is

```
<div class="workgroup_title" style="color:"#<xsl:value-of select="./abc.xyz.color"/>>
  <xsl:value-of select="./@name"/>
</div>
```

That's not allowed, though.

Or:

```
<xsl:attribute style="color:">#<xsl:value-of select="./abc.xyz.color"/></xsl:attribute>
```

But `color` is not one of the attributes that can be set like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use attribute value templates to compute (parts of) the value of a literal result element: `<div style="color: #{abc.xyz.color}">...</div>`

Comment: Awesome! Curly braces? Who knew?! Is that XSLT 1.0?

Comment: @dzmr83, sure, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates, available since XSLT 1.

Answer (score 1):

The following templates should suffice your needs:

```
<xsl:template match="text()" />                      <!-- Removes the text from the <abc.xyz.color>FF5733</abc.xyz.color> element -->

<xsl:template match="/*">                            <!-- Copies the root element and its namespace -->
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="div[@class='workgroup_title']"> <!-- Applies the template to the <div> element -->
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="style"><xsl:value-of select="concat('color: #',../abc.xyz.color,';')"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**Its output is:**

```
<root xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <div style="color: #FF5733;" class="workgroup_title">
        <xsl:value-of select="./@name"/>
    </div>
</root>
```